# Microsoft Teams delete comment from another user

Tags: microsoft-teams

**How can I delete a comment from another user in the channel?**

I am the team owner, I have an option to delete my comment, in comment from another user I don't have that option.

Is it also possible not show notification for added user to a team in the channel?

Comment: No, You cannot delete the comments from another user. You can uncheck the checkbox regarding the notifications not to send while installing your app to a channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option in messaging policies In the Teams admin center that allow owners to delete messages in a Team.